# Applied for the wrong visa

Tags: ancestry-visas

I’ve applied for the Wrong visa!! I applied for the right to abode instead of ancestry visa (I am eligible as my grand father was born in the uk). I couldn’t find the ancestry visa in the pull down tabs.

I’ve booked my appointment and have paid for the visa already. Can I just go the the appointment and explain I selected the wrong visa? Or should I apply for the correct one?

If I apply for a new visa will the issue a refund for the one I’ve already applied for (right to abode)

Comment: By the time you get to your appointment, most of the work of processing your application, such as reviewing the documents, has already been done. I would be surprised if you could get a refund.

Comment: Better to cancel the incorrect application and apply afresh. You should get a refund if you cancel before your appointment.

Answer (score 2):

[Cancel](https://www.gov.uk/cancel-visa) your application as soon as possible, and hope that the application "hasn't been processed yet," in which case you should be able to get a refund:

> ## Cancel your visa, immigration or citizenship application
>
> You can ask to cancel (withdraw) an application for a visa, visa extension or citizenship.
>
> How you cancel an application depends on where you applied.
>
> ### You applied outside the UK
>
> [Contact UKVI](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk) to find out how to cancel your application.
>
> You can only get your fee refunded if your application hasn’t been processed yet.

Then file a new application for the correct visa.